# How to show Comment Count in node template?

Tags: theming, 8, nodes, comments

How can I show ***Comment Count*** in a specific place of the node template?
I want to show Comment Count's of a node (article) in the submitted area instead of in the node links area. 
I do this already in Drupal 7 with this codes in node.tpl.php:

```
<?php if (module_exists('comment') && $node->comment) { print t('Comments'). ': ' .$node->comment_count;} ?>
```

or this code:

```
<a href="<?php print $node_url;?>#comments"><?php print t('Comments'). ': '. $comment_count; ?></a>
```

What is the equivalent code for Drupal 8?

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Please reopen this post, This question is about Drupal 8 but that's about Drupal 7, `node.tpl`

Comment: No, that question is not for Drupal 7. It doesn't have any version tag, and there is an answer for Drupal 8.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this code in your theme's `YOUR_THEME.theme` file:

```
function YOUR_THEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  // Note: you'll probably want this only for certain content types.
  if ($variables['node']->getType() == 'YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE') {
    $variables['comment_count'] = $variables['node']->get('YOUR_COMMENT_FIELD')->comment_count;
  }
}
```

And then you can use it in your `node.html.twig` file like so:

```
{{ comment_count }}
```

Comment: Thank you for your efforts, but i don't know where is the problem that howsoever I trying to get a result, i can't become success. Could you explain more about this code, How should I use this code in my theme?

Comment: I mentioned where each piece of code should go to; I don't completely understand your question. The first part (`hook_preprocess_node()`) goes into `YOUR_THEME.theme` file. The other part is how you use that in your node templates. If this is not what you meant, please explain.

Comment: Those are machine names for your content type and your comment field. Machine name is displayed under the label. For example, when you are adding "Article" content type, your machine name will be "article"; if you create "Article Comments" field, machine name will be "field_article_comments".

Comment: [Content type](http://i.imgur.com/IOrbhaF.png) machine name, and [field](http://i.imgur.com/WiCfjwj.png) machine name.

Comment: You're welcome - glad it helped :)